# copy file given it url

Tags: java, file, copy

I have textual file containing urls of image files.

I want to copy those files from other directory.

This code doesn't work

```
    File source =//
    File target = //
    File urls = //
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(urls);
    for (File child :source.listFiles())
     {
         if (child.isDirectory()) 

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            for (File childOfchild:child.listFiles())
             {
                 if (childOfchild.getAbsolutePath().contains(line))

                               FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(childOfchild,target);

             }

            }
    }
```

What is the problem?

the first file contain urls of image that i want to copy

```
    \actor\0211_2233188435.jpg
    \actor\0405_52447453.jpg
```

the source location contain 704 subdirectories and 250000 files 
for examlpe

```
    /media/B68E392F8E38E98F/Flickr1/Flickr/actor/0001_2124494179.jpg
```

Comment: what is the error ??......

Comment: the file contain 175OO urls 
and only 40 image are copied

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: @linski my operating system is ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is the postion of while instruction

```
File source =//
File target = //
File urls = //
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(urls);
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
 for (File child :source.listFiles())
 {
     if (child.isDirectory()) 



        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        for (File childOfchild:child.listFiles())
         {
             if (childOfchild.getAbsolutePath().contains(line))

                           FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(childOfchild,target);

         }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the recursion, in the net you can find examples. [This is one of them:](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/)

```
public void copyDirectory(File sourceLocation , File targetLocation) throws IOException {
    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: this code copy all files from one directory to another 
i need to copy files that i have it urls 

i will edir my question to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

The code below copies the entire file structure of the sourceDir to the destDir using sequential approach. I'm not familiar with `apache-commons` lib so it is possible that there is a more elegant solution.

```
public static String getNewPath(File file,File source,File dest) throws IOException {
    String filePath = file.getCanonicalPath().replaceAll(source.getCanonicalPath(), "");        
    return dest.getCanonicalPath()+filePath;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File sourceDir = new File("./f_src");
    File destDir = new File("./f_dest");
    Collection<File> fs = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(sourceDir, TrueFileFilter.TRUE, TrueFileFilter.TRUE);
    for (File f : fs) {
        if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                FileUtils.copyFile(f, new File(getNewPath(f,sourceDir,destDir)));                    
            }
            else {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(f, new File(getNewPath(f,sourceDir,destDir)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code assumes that within your root project directory exist two directories namely `f_src` and `f_dest`. This was my test file structure for `f_src`, numbers are directories and letters are files:

```
f_src
   |\-1
   | |\-2
   | | | \-3
   | | |   \-a
   | |  \-b
   |  \-c
   |\-4 
   |  |\-5
   |  |   \-d
   |   \-e
   |\-6
   |\-7
   |  \-f
   \-g
```